# Method not found error importing custom SSIS components into VS 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I am trying to learn how to build custom SSIS components. Naturally, after looking through the documentation, the next thing I went for were some tutorials. They're thin on the ground and a few years out of date, but they do work.

Trying to use what I'd learned I successfully built a simple validation component and was able to drag it into an SSIS package. Howevever, when I tried to use it, I got the following error:

> The component has detected potential metadata corruption during
>   validation. Error at Data Flow Task [Data Masker [40]]:
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.DataType
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSInputColumn100.get_DataType()'.
>   at EmailValidation.DataMasker.Validate()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostValidate(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
>   wrapper)

Naturally, I presumed I'd done something wrong, but I couldn't see what. After trying several times to solve the issue I went back to one of the tutorials and downloaded the code. It was a built in VS 2010 so I copied the code into VS 2015 and tried to deploy the component - got the same error.

After doing some more experimentation, this seem to be consistent. The components will build fine in any version of visual studio. And they work in earlier versions of BIDS. But on trying to use them in a VS 2015 package it generates this error.

I can find no references to this in searching at all. Can anyone explain what's going on here?